# How do I initialize a 3D Velocity field with a 1D velocity vector?

Tags: computational-physics, vector-fields, flow

I have a 1D flame solution, with velocity magnitude. I want to transform this into a 3D velocity field that is symmetric in all directions. It is an expanding spherical flame.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I'm assuming you have a number $u$ and want to transform it to a vector $\vec{v} = (w,w,w)$ such that $|\vec{v}| = u$? This assumes that $u$ is positive, as you said it was a magnitude.

Well $|\vec{v}| = \sqrt{3w^2} = \sqrt{3}|w|$, so choosing $w =\pm \frac{u}{\sqrt{3}}$ should do the trick?

This leaves you with a sign ambiguity, because you only know the magnitude. You're saying the flame is expanding, so a natural solution to choose would be:
$$
\vec{v} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{pmatrix} u\\ u \\ u\end{pmatrix}
$$

Though a word of caution: the fact that you know the magnitude tells you nothing about the direction, so there are an infinite number of possible vectors corresponding to your magnitude. If you are sure that the field is expanding and symmetric in all directions, then the above solution is a way to go.

Comment: I think the OP wants *all* radially directed vectors with the given magnitude, but I also think the question is confusing.

Comment: So basically I want to carry out a DNS of an expanding spherical flame. The Initial conditions are obtained from a 1D solver (i use a in house code, but something like cantera). The idea is based on the position of a point relative to the origin, which is at the middle of a cubic domain, I want to obtain the velocity vectors whose magnitude will be the magnitude from the 1D solution.

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to obtain all possible velocity vectors which correspond to the given magnitude and point radially? Or what constraints do you have on your velocity vectors (in general there are an infinite number of vectors corresponding to any given magnitude)?

Comment: Yes, it should point radially outwards, be symmetrical, and should have the magnitude at any distance from the origin to be equal to the magnitude given by the 1D velocity vector. In the end if I travel along a line from the origin to some distance, the resultant of the velocity vectors should give me the original 1D velocity I started with. To simplify I would say I want to reconstruct a 3D sphericaly expanding flame from a 1d solution.